# Notepad (app created in c#) don't read text at start

Tags: c#

I have a simple notepad with a rich text box. I have build the project to see if it works. I can open files with openFileDialog or save files with saveFileDialog.

The problem is :
if I set this notepad to by default program to open text files on windows, text doesn't appear in the notepad. 
how can I make a function to read text when I open notepad.

UPDATE: If i set my notepad to by default text editor on the Windows i can open the notepad, and i can open or save files. The problem appear when i open a text file directly from the desktop/explorer. When i double click to the file, My Notepad is opening, but the text from the file not appear.

I am beginner at programmer, so any kind of help will be much appreciated.

I am trying to use this as constructor:

```
  using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(file))
                   {
                      w.Write(patch); 
                      w.Close();
                   }
```

But this is not working. I know I need a function when program start, but I don't know how can I write it.

Comment: what is the definition of `patch` ?

Comment: path = openFileDialog1.FileName; 
but is not working here, is working only to open files like Open buton:
openFileDialog -> and get patch

Comment: Still, I don't get the idea, what is the `patch` means

Comment: i use the patch to open files and save the location of the files 
c\PC\desktop\text.txt - this is the path

Comment: Can you supply more code when you open with dialogue box and when initialized.

Comment: ok. i will paste below the code

Answer (score 2):

The filename you double-click on in Explorer will be passed as an args parameter to your notepad app. So you can get the file path like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args){            
     string path = args[0];
     Application.Run(new Notepad(path));           
}
```

Comment: If i open a file,notepad can read text, but if i have a text file on the desktop and i double click on the file and i set default notepad my notepad , the aplication cant read the text

Comment: what i mean:
I open the Notepad. I use File/Open - can read text
I use File/Save - the text is saved.

But if i open directly the text file from the desktop, the notepad dont read text

Comment: @Owen Pauling: I think, he made custom notepad application and try to open .txt file with it CMIIW.

Comment: i just double click on a text file, and text dont apear.

i need to use open button to display text... he dont apear directly

Comment: u right Heinz Siahaan.... notepad show text only if i use Open Button, but i want to open text if i press double click on text file on the desktop.

Comment: So, if you use open button, it's OK? I think you set default value for `path` variable somewhere, so it's not load your designated file (to be opened by double click).

Comment: yes, i don't know to make a function to load text if i double click on a file from desktop. this is the only issue

Comment: is not about save or open files from the BUTTONS. I just wanna double click a file on desktop (notepad does not run yet) ... after i double click notepad open but with no text

Comment: Changed answer based on your clarification

Answer (score 1):

Here is an application that will read text from file if it is set as default file reader or if you drag-and-drop file to this app EXE.
This is console app but you should grasp a concept.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SampleFileOpener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);

                if (File.Exists(arg))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(); //Empty line
                    var content = File.ReadAllText(arg);
                    Console.WriteLine(content);
                    Console.WriteLine(); //Empty line
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try to do something with my notepad... i make a lot of funtions in my custom notepad, but is so sad when is not working well...

Answer (score 1):

In Form.cs (that contains designer), you can add this:

```
  public void readOnOpen(string fileName)
        {
            path = fileName;
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                // Write to file 
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(path);

            }
        }
```

In program.cs, you can add this:

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //check whether you get this by double-clicking file or debug with compiler
            if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
            {
                //if args is not NULL, it means you do it by double-clicking files
               //so, you can get the filename by getting the args
                string fileName = args[0];
                //Check file exists
                if (File.Exists(fileName))
                {
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                    Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
                    //this would call method open (like with open dialogue)
                    //you can get path or filename from args in Main Form
                    //MainForm is your notepad form
                    MainForm.readOnOpen(fileName);


                    Application.Run(MainForm);
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
```

Comment: i will try this tnx :)